# CodeIgniter index.php removal htaccess causing mis-redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using following htaccess rule which is proposed all over internet for removing index.php in codeigniter urls. And there are some of the redirection rules i added above it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

The problem is:
I'm getting some odd http request, which i think is caused by htaccess rules above.
Here are some of them :

https://www.sitename.com/index.php/favicon.ico
which ought to be .com/favicon.ico

https://www.sitename.com/index.php/scripts/jquery.js
which ought to be .com/public/jquery.js
**as a side note im using base tag to redirect assets to /public/**

strange thing is i couldnt find where the second redirection happens
i tested whole site and javascript & css files load correctly

i handled this redirections by making my controller ignore those requests but a while ago
a strange error happened. which i asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775849/htaccess-didnt-work-until-renaming-and-then-renaming-back

my guess is that, even though i ignore misredirected request, hosting company receives them and probably it was causing some trouble for them which led to the problem i shared in linked question by a maintenance of hosting company.

Anyway, Question is:
**How can i make htaccess rule only redirect requests that doesnt have file extension at the end?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a line before the `REQUEST_FILENAME` line:

```
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|something|fav\.ico|robots\.txt)
```

You can modify this to suit your needs. I've got my JS/CSS etc in the `assets` folder so it's not affected by the rewrite.

so the full `.htaccess` will look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|something|fav\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```